# Passing variable from function to outside the function

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get a variable (listID) passed from the function to outside the function and I'm getting the result as undefined. I see this requires a callback, but I'm not clear on how to do this (I'm new to nodejs).
Can anybody show me how this would be done? Thanks.

```
twitter.get('/lists/list', function(err, data, response) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var j=i+1;
    if (j==number){
        var listID=data[i].id;
     }
    }
  });

console.log(listID);
```

Comment: What is it that you need to do? why can't you do it inside the callback?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to do this inside the callback...I need the variable listID for other processing (including making this the parameter of another function.

Comment: Create function and call it when you find `listID`. I recommend learn asynchronous idea. It's popular question.

Comment: Thanks Aikon...sorry but can you take my code and show how to create the function, call it when listID id determined.  I'm very new at this and can learn when I see an example. Thanks